# How is calculated the error with multiple output neurons in neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, multiclass-classification, perceptron

Machine Learning books generally explains that the error calculated for a given sample $i$ is:

$e_i = y_i - \hat{y_i}$

Where $\hat{y}$ is the target output and $y$ is the actual output given by the network. So, a loss function $L$ is calculated:

$L = \frac{1}{2N}\sum^{N}_{i=1}(e_i)^2$

The above scenario is explained for a binary classification/regression problem. Now, let's assume a MLP network with $m$ neurons in the output layer for a multiclass classification problem (generally one neuron per class).

What does change in the equations above? Since we now have multiple outputs, both $e_i$ and $y_i$ should be a vector?

Comment: I thought that every neuron would have its $L$. For instance, for neuron $m$: $L_m = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}(e_{im})^2$

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing various concepts:

- $L = \frac{1}{2N}\sum^{N}_{i=1}(e_i)^2$ is used only for regression problem and not for binary classification because MSE fits very well when your target distribution is normal
- You can use the latter formula for binary classification but will works really bad because your target data distribution is a Bernoulli, not Normal. Remember that the choice of the right imply a prior assumption on the target data distribution. For this reason the right formula is binary crossentropy (aka negative log likelihood of a Bernoulli) $$ L = - \sum_i y_i \log \hat{y_i} (1 - y_i) \log(1 - \hat{y_i})   $$
- For multi classification problem there is a generalized formula of binary crossentropy which is called categorical crossentropy. If $\hat{y}$ is a vector of C element, one for each class and the true class $y$ is encoded as integer (e.g 0, 1, 2 ...) then the loss is $$ L = - \sum_i \log(\hat{y_i}[y]) $$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've seen some models built with cross-entropy (e.g. Keras and Tensorflow). However, classical books still use MSE as loss criteria... in that case, does it make sense if the error is a vector?

Comment: Honestly I never seen any book that use mse for binary classification and if you have such book you should change book. If i can suggest one very well writter check this https://www.deeplearningbook.org/ .  MSE it makes sense also on predicted vectors (a common case are images) just add a sum term for each element of the vector

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: MSE in a classification problem is known as “Brier score” and has been used to train image classifiers.